# ZF2 Managing Forms and Entities from one place

Tags: doctrine-orm, crud, zend-framework2

I want to know how people are implementing basic CRUD in ZF2.

I've been playing with it for a week or two using Doctrine ORM and the best solution I have is to implement an entity class and then a form class to match the entity.

Does ZF2 not have a nice way to manage all of this from one place similar to RoR? eg If I add a new field to my Entity I don't want to have to add a new field in the form class as well. I don't even want to have to have a form class for simple forms.

I've also tried annotations and they worked somewhat but it seems they have issues with getting an object manager when your form field is a related entity. I found a github issue about this.

Answer (score 2):

Annotations would be your only way to have a `one-for-all`Solution.

Personally i separate my code quite a bit to follow the SoC-Principle (Separation of Concerns). I have one Class for my Entity. I have another class for the Form. Yet another class to provide InputFilters and Validators and i also use Factory classes to instantiate stuff that has dependencies (like the EntityManager for Doctrine Form Elements).

Ultimately it boils down to personal preference i guess. I see my approach a little cleaner than working with annotations. Annotations are a little bit slower, too, since they need to parse the file (again, next to the Entity builder), so caching should be considered.